# get this JSON representation of your neo4j objects

Tags: groovy, neo4j

I want to get data from thisarray of  json object :

```
[
    {
        "outgoing_relationships": "http://myserver:7474/db/data/node/4/relationships/out",
        "data": {
            "family": "3",
            "batch": "/var/www/utils/batches/d32740d8-b4ad-49c7-8ec8-0d54fcb7d239.resync",
            "name": "rahul",
            "command": "add",
            "type": "document"
        },
        "traverse": "http://myserver:7474/db/data/node/4/traverse/{returnType}",
        "all_typed_relationships": "http://myserver:7474/db/data/node/4/relationships/all/{-list|&|types}",
        "property": "http://myserver:7474/db/data/node/4/properties/{key}",
        "self": "http://myserver:7474/db/data/node/4",
        "properties": "http://myserver:7474/db/data/node/4/properties",
        "outgoing_typed_relationships": "http://myserver:7474/db/data/node/4/relationships/out/{-list|&|types}",
        "incoming_relationships": "http://myserver:7474/db/data/node/4/relationships/in",
        "extensions": {},
        "create_relationship": "http://myserver:7474/db/data/node/4/relationships",
        "paged_traverse": "http://myserver:7474/db/data/node/4/paged/traverse/{returnType}{?pageSize,leaseTime}",
        "all_relationships": "http://myserver:7474/db/data/node/4/relationships/all",
        "incoming_typed_relationships": "http://myserver:7474/db/data/node/4/relationships/in/{-list|&|types}"
    }
]
```

what i tried is :

```
  def messages=[];
  for ( i in families) {
      messages?.add(i);
  }
```

how i can get familes.data.name in message array .

Here is what i tried :

```
def messages=[];
  for ( i in families) {
    def map = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(i);
     def msg=map*.data.name;
   messages?.add(i);
  }
  return messages;
```

and get this error :

```
 javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: groovy.json.JsonSlurper.parseText() is applicable for argument types: (com.tinkerpop.blueprints.pgm.impls.neo4j.Neo4jVertex) values: [v[4]]\nPossible solutions: parseText(java.lang.String), parse(java.io.Reader)
```

Comment: Those parsers work on a String, not on a Neo4jVertex. Try passing a String with JSON contents to them.

Comment: because your array is NOT JSON! it is an array of strings and those strings are NOT JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or use Groovy's native JSON parsing:

```
def families = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText( jsonAsString )
def messages = families*.data.name
```

Since you edited the question to give us the information we needed, you can try:

```
def messages=[];
families.each { i ->
  def map = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText( i.toString() )
  messages.addAll( map*.data.name )
}
messages
```

Though it should be said that the `toString()` method in `com.tinkerpop.blueprints.pgm.impls.neo4j.Neo4jVertex` makes no guarantees to be valid JSON...  **You should probably be using the `getProperty( name )` function of `Neo4jVertex` rather than relying on a side-effect of `toString()`**

What are you doing to generate the first bit of text (which you state is JSON and make no mention of how it's created)

Comment: @RahulMehta Right, now you've put the important information in the question, you can see that the thing at the top is a `toString()` representation of a `com.tinkerpop.blueprints.pgm.impls.neo4j.Neo4jVertex` object...  try: `parseText( i.toString() )`

Comment: i am getting this error after trying .toString() javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.json.JsonException: Lexing failed on line: 1, column: 1, while reading 'v', no possible valid JSON value or punctuation could be recognized.

Comment: @RahulMehta Unless you answer how you got the "JSON" you posted in your question, there's not much else I can do to help as my crystal ball is at the menders this week.  Did you see my comment about using `getProperty` instead of this round-about method?  That may hold true, but it really depends how you got the JSON text...

Answer (score 1):

Use [JSON-lib](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/groovy.html).

```
GJson.enhanceClasses()
def families = json_string as JSONArray

def messages = families.collect {it.data.name}
```

Comment: how json_string can be as JSONarray

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Groovy 1.8, you don't need JSON-lib anymore as a [JsonSlurper](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html) is included in the GDK.

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def families = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json_string)
def messages = families.collect { it.data.name }
```

Comment: How did you define families? It's not a string containing your JSON, apparently.

Comment: OK, what you actually want is to convert a neo4j graphs to a JSON string,  right?

Comment: yeah i think so i am getting it blueprints results = autoIndex.get("country","belarus"); index.get function https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/wiki/Graph-Indices and i want to take data from this input